# What is a Delta table in a directory as it pertains to Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

If I were to ask the question
What is a Delta table in a directory?
Which of the following would be the correct answer

a) It is a directory containing data files

b) It is a single file containing the data

c) It is a subdirectory that is named based on partition values

d) It is a JSON file containing a snapshot of the table

I was asked this question as part of a mock exam. I'm interested to know what you think the answer is.

I thought the answer was It is a single file containing the data

Thanks

Comment: A Delta table is actually a directory that contains data files, metadata, and other artifacts related to the table.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for getting in touch, there the correct answer would be Answer: c) It is a subdirectory that is named based on partition values. Correct?

Comment: no, it's not answer

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reaching out. What would you is the correct answer?

Comment: I meant to say what would you say is the correct answer ?

Comment: Hi Alex, on second I think the answer C is correct. If you re-read the question it states What is a Delta table in a directory?

Comment: Weird question if you've posted it exactly. Option A should be the answer if we're not word-playing. See [this](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/format:webp/1*L1yM-xDaIUNMSIoanVr8BA.png)

Comment: Hi, o, thanks for reaching out. I admit the question does come across a word play, however, if you take a look at your image you will see that the delta table _delta_log is indeed a subdirectory of root diectory my_table.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: This is exam prep. They need to RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is usually stored in multiple files(partitions) and along with it are stored the historic tables and the log files, hence A would be the answer.